# whats the best way to style a background image on a textbox ex:searchbox

Tags: html, css

I've done this before but for some reason im trying to right now and im using fieldset to display the background image and i can only get it to look nice in firefox. Whats a good cross-browser solution to adding a background image to a textbox.

example i was trying

```
<div class="subscribe">
                <form method="get" id="searcform" action="">
                    <fieldset class="search">
                        <input type="text" class="box" value="Subscribe to Email Newsletter" />
                        <button class="btn" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: And by 'textbox' you mean `<input type="text" />` or `<textarea>`..?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what element you mean, but the following should work:

```
input[type=text],
textarea {
    background: #fff url(path/to/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: i meant this and i was using <fieldset> where i was setting a round input image as the background
<input type="textbox" class="textbox" name="subscribe" />

Comment: @josh: please edit the further details into the *question*, and, if possible, provide a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your input transparent and place inside a container div.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LRWWH/

Cross browser friendly.